# Metasploitable 3 Build on windows 11 - errors

Tags: windows, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, packer

Trying to build a Metasploitable 3 on virtual box on windows 11.

Running powershell command below:

```
PS C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\Metasploitable3> ./build.ps1 windows2008
```

Returned after sending command:

```
'''
Compatible version of VirtualBox found.
Compatible version of Packer found.
Compatible version of Vagrant found.
Compatible version of vagrant-reload plugin found.
All requirements found. Proceeding...
Building metasploitable3-win2k8 Vagrant box...
virtualbox-iso output will be in this color.

==> virtualbox-iso: Downloading or copying Guest additions
    virtualbox-iso: Downloading or copying: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
==> virtualbox-iso: Downloading or copying ISO
    virtualbox-iso: Downloading or copying: http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/5/E/75EC4E54-5B02-42D6-8879-D8D3A25FBEF7/7601.17514.101119-1850_x64fre_server_eval_en-us-GRMSXEVAL_EN_DVD.iso
    virtualbox-iso: Error downloading: checksums didn't match expected: 4263be2cf3c59177c45085c0a7bc6ca5
==> virtualbox-iso: ISO download failed.
Build 'virtualbox-iso' errored: ISO download failed.

==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
--> virtualbox-iso: ISO download failed.

==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.
Error building the Vagrant box using Packer. Please check the output above for any error messages.
At C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\Metasploitable3\build.ps1:157 char:10
+          throw "Error building the Vagrant box using Packer. Please c ...
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Error building ...error messages.:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Error building the Vagrant box using Packer. Please check the output above for any error
    messages.
'''
```

Comment: Can you add the contents of your `build.ps1`-script? So others can see what you've done, and maybe learn from it...

Answer (score 0):

I can see that the `.iso` you're trying to download gives a 404:

https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/5/E/75EC4E54-5B02-42D6-8879-D8D3A25FBEF7/7601.17514.101119-1850_x64fre_server_eval_en-us-GRMSXEVAL_EN_DVD.iso

Try to change that link in your script, so it points to an existing `.iso`-file.

Answer (score 0):

I too have been looking to build a fresh Metasploitable 3 VM recently. Unfortunately, the build process starts by first downloading an ISO of 7601.17514.101119-1850_x64fre_server_eval_en-us-GRMSXEVAL_EN_DVD.iso which is the Windows Server 2008 evaluation DVD image file, and Microsoft appears to have removed that from their downloadable files offerings. To proceed, you (and I) will have to find another source for this ISO, and so far I've had no luck with sourcing the file. Best of luck - hopefully things will go better for you than they have for me on seeking this file.